# Chrome - background-size: cover;-based gallery causes performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, vuejs2, background-size

I'm building an app using Vue 2. There's a page that contains a simple image gallery that contains about 20 images and one large page background image.

The background image of the page itself is actually contained in a fixed `div` element that is `position: fixed;`, has 100% `width` and `height` and uses `background-size: cover;` to display the image.

All of the ~20 items in the gallery as well are using `div` elements with `background-size: cover;` displayed in a 3-column grid and the images are displayed using the dynamically generated `background-url` CSS property using a Vue computed property. The image paths are never being changed so they aren't being recomputed constantly AFAIK.

The performance of this page in Chrome is abysmal, loading takes forever (those are some high resolution images, though, 4K in width) and once the images are loaded I can somewhat interact with the page but everything is extremely laggy and sometimes the page stops responding completely.

On the other hand, in Firefox and Edge everything is basically buttery smooth, both during the loading of the images and during the scrolling/rendering. The interaction with the app is never blocked.

What I remember trying to fix this is replacing the `div` elements with regular `img` tags and loading up images using those. Also, I've tried caching the images, I've tried using static image URLs for testing purposes - the same thing happens every time - other browsers handle it well, Chrome is choking on it.

Here's a screenshot of the performance summary in ~30 seconds, from the moment I click the page URL to the moment that basically everything is loaded and the browser is still struggling to render anything and process any interaction with the page. Obviously the painting phase is an issue here:

[image: Performance screenshot]

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: okay, seems like you really have some interesting issue there.
Can you show a screenshot with detailed breakdown like in the following chart:
https://www.kisspng.com/png-computer-program-javascript-google-chrome-web-page-5594250/
Increase the size of the developer tools window to get a bigger view of the breakdown. Click into the breakdown and use the keyboard key A S W D to zoom and move in the chart.

Comment: Sure I'll gather the data and post it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer as it is a very specific problem.

You can analyze what is causing this behaviour in chrome by using the developer tools:

1. Open the developer tools in chrome by pressing "Ctrl+Shift+I".
2. Go to the tab "Performance".
3. Hit the record button and do the action which has low performance.
4. Hit stop and you get a breakdown what happened in the background.

If you don't find the issue with above suggestion, you can post a detailed screenshot of the performance breakdown here, I might be able to help you with it.

Comment: Added a screenshot as requested.